# DRF what's the difference between serializers(many=True) vs ListField(serializer())

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When should I use each of the following?

```
* MySerializer(many=True)
* serializers.ListField(child=MySerializer())
```

Answer (score 3):

`MySerializer(many=True)` - you can use when `MySerializer` makes some serialization of each of your objects.
`serializers.ListField(child=MySerializer())` - this one you can use if you want to serialize not only objects, but result iterable data too.

For example, you want to append for each object its position in result list:

```
class ListSerializerWithIds(serializers.ListSerializer):
    @property
    def data(self):
        data = super().data

        result = []
        for i, d in enumerate(data):
            d["list_id"] = i
            result.append(d)
        return result

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a = serializer.CharField()

    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["child"] = cls()
        return ListSerializerWithIds(*args, **kwargs)
```

now, if you will get result data of `MySerializer` it will be looks like:

```
objects = [{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}, {"a": "a2", "c": "c2"}]
serializer = MySerializer(objects, many=True)
serializer.data
# [{"a": "a1", "list_id": 0}, {"a": "a2", "list_id": 1}]
```

Also, you can use `serializers.ListField(child=MySerializer())` as a field of another serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a = serializers.CharField()

class AnotherSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_data = serializers.ListField(child=MySerializer())
```

Now see the result:

```
objects = [{"my_data": [{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}], "tralala": "blablabla"}, ]
serializer = AnotherSerializer(objects, many=True)
serializer.data
# [{"my_data": [{"a": "a1"}]}, ]
```