# Serialize ManyToManyField with foreign key of nested

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to serialize attributes of an item related from many to many, but grouped by each type of attribute.

Models

```
    from django.db import models


    class AtributoTipo(models.Model):
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)


    class Atributo(models.Model):
        tipo = models.ForeignKey(AtributoTipo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)


    class Articulo(models.Model):
        codigo = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique=True, db_index=True)
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        atributos = models.ManyToManyField(Atributo, related_name="articulos")
```

Normal DRF serializers:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers

    class AtributoTipoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = AtributoTipo
            fields = ["__all__"]


    class AtributoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        tipo_slug = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="tipo.slug")
        tipo_nombre = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="tipo.nombre")
        class Meta:
            model = Atributo
            fields = ["__all__"]


    class ArticuloSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        atributos = AtributoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) # the dude
        class Meta:
            model = Articulo
            fields = ["__all__"]
```

This is the result with serializers without any weird method:

```
    {
        "id": 44906,
        "codigo": "DE0058751",
        "atributos": [
            {
                "id": 15107,
                "tipo": 76,
                "tipo_slug": "talla",
                "tipo_nombre": "Talla",
                "nombre": "39",
                "slug": "39"
            },
            {
                "id": 43454,
                "tipo": 76,
                "tipo_slug": "talla",
                "tipo_nombre": "Talla",
                "nombre": "40",
                "slug": "40"
            },
            {
                "id": 23234,
                "tipo": 15,
                "tipo_slug": "color",
                "tipo_nombre": "Color",
                "nombre": "Rojo",
                "slug": "rojo"
            },
            {
                "id": 12408,
                "tipo": 15,
                "tipo_slug": "color",
                "tipo_nombre": "Color",
                "nombre": "Verde",
                "slug": "verde"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Desired result:

```
    {
        "id": 44906,
        "codigo": "DE0058751",
        "atributos": [
            {
                "id": 76,
                "slug": "talla",
                "nombre": "Talla",
                "atributos": [
                    {
                        "id": 15107,
                        "tipo": 76,
                        "nombre": "39",
                        "slug": "39"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12408,
                        "tipo": 76,
                        "nombre": "40",
                        "slug": "40"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "slug": "color",
                "nombre": "Color",
                "atributos": [
                    {
                        "id": 34234,
                        "tipo": 15,
                        "nombre": "Rojo",
                        "slug": "rojo"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2323,
                        "tipo": 15,
                        "nombre": "Verde",
                        "slug": "verde"
                    }
                ]
            }                    
        ]
    }
```

The problem is that you lose the context of the article.
I tried itertools groupby, but I think there must be another logic with DRF.

Comment: your desired output is not clear. Why do you need atributos, inside atributos? Your output is exactly what have written code for.

Comment: The main is the "articulo", "atributos" of "articulo" grouped by "atributotipo", maybe: "atributostipos": [
            {
                "id": 76,
                "slug": "talla",
                "nombre": "Talla",
                "atributos": [
                    {
                       ...
I think it can't be done, I'll end up creating serialized functions

Comment: Another approach?

Comment: @Diego check out my response here ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/62235965/8548036 ) and redefine `many_init` method in `AtributoSerializer`. Your return value in new `many_init` method must be a new `ListSerializer` with goup by in `data` property. If you need I can write an answer here with some additional comments etc

Comment: I'll try your solution

Comment: @ncopiy Sorry, I don't know how to apply your example to my code

Comment: @Diego check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `to_representation` of `ListSerializer` and use `ListSerializer` as a field of your `ArticuloSerializer`:

```
class GroupedAttributosSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = super().to_representation(data)

        tipo_slug_to_objects = defaultdict(list)
        for d in data:
            tipo_slug_to_objects[d["tipo_slug"]].append(d)

        result = []

        for tipo_slug, objects in tipo_slug_to_objects.items():
            result.append(
                {
                    "id": objects[0]["tipo"],
                    "slug": tipo_slug,
                    "nombre": objects[0]["tipo_nombre"],
                    "attributos": [
                        {"id": attribute["id"],
                        "tipo": attribute["tipo"],
                        "nombre": attribute["nombre"],
                        "slug": attribute["slug"]}
                        for attribute in objects
                    ]
                }
            )
        return result

class ArticuloSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    atributos = GroupedAttributosSerializer(child=AtributoSerializer(), read_only=True, default=[])

    class Meta:
        model = Articulo
        fields = ["__all__"]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Do you think this solution can greatly affect the loading speed?

Comment: @Diego i think no - because there is no high complexity of `to_representation` function and no any excess database requests

Comment: "+1" for accessing the data like this ( data = super().to_representation(data) )before returning the same ( super().to_representation(data) ) otherwise it wont possible to assign new key value pair to the response.